# How to use Jenkins CI pipeline code in python

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am new to Jenkins, and I need to use python to read some user credentials which are stored on Jenkins, I am confused about how to do that.

I have created some global credentials in my local jenkins. I want to use python to read and use these credentials.

[image]

The above photo is the credential I created.

I also have some jenkins CI pipeline code for reading and using the credentials, and I want to know is there some way allow me to use them in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use `withCredentials` block, you can use `uname` and `pass` as the environment variables. I'm not good at Python, but `os.environ['uname']` and `os.environ['pass']` can be used inside the block.